# Unable to read environment variables in Django using django_configurations package

Tags: python, django

I was using `django-environ` to manage env variables, everything was working fine, recently I moved to [django-configurations](https://django-configurations.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).

My settings inherit `configurations.Configuration` but I am having trouble getting values from `.env` file. For example, while retrieving `DATABASE_NAME` it gives the following error:
`TypeError: object of type 'Value' has no len()`

I know the below code returns a `value.Value` instance instead of a string, but I am not sure why it does so. The same is the case with every other env variable:

My `.env.` file is as follows:

```
DEBUG=True
DATABASE_NAME='portfolio_v1'
SECRET_KEY='your-secrete-key'
```

`settings.py` file is as follows

```
 ...
 from configurations import Configuration, values
 DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'NAME': values.Value("DATABASE_NAME", environ=True),
 ...
```

I have verified that my `.env' file exists and is on the valid path.

Answer (score 0):

I spent more time resolving the above issue and found what was missing.
Prefixing `.env` variables is mandatory in `django-configuration` as a default behavior.

While dealing `dict` keys, we have to provide `environ_name` `kwarg` to the Value instance

NOTE: .env variables should be prefixed with `DJANGO_` even if you provide  `environ_name`. If you want to override the prefix you have to provide `environ_prefix`) i.e.

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': values.Value(environ_name="DATABASE_NAME"), # provide DJANGO_DATABASE_NAME='portfolio_v1' in .env file
```

other use cases are:

```
VAR = values.Value()   # works, provided DJANGO_VAR='var_value'
VAR = values.Value(environ_prefix='MYSITE')    # works, provided MYSITE_VAR='var_value'
CUSTOM_DICT = {
    'key_1': values.Value(environ_required=True),  # doesn't work
    'key_2': values.Value(environ_name='other_key'), # works if provided DJANGO_key_2='value_2' in .env
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using django-configurations in the wrong way.

See the [source code](https://django-configurations.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/configurations/values.html#Value) of the Value class:

```
class Value:
    @property
    def value(self):
       ...
    def __init__(self, default=None, environ=True, environ_name=None,
                 environ_prefix='DJANGO', environ_required=False,
                 *args, **kwargs):
       ...
```

So you want to have the default value not as "DATABASE_NAME", and your environment variable in your `.env` file should start with `DJANGO_`.

Then to use the value you can use the value property, so your settings file should look like:

```
...
 from configurations import Configuration, values
 DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'NAME': values.Value("DEFAULT_VAL").value, 
                    # No need for environ=True since it is default
 ...
```